# How to receive message through Broadcast Receiver when app is killed

Tags: android

This is my onReceive method

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if(intent.getAction()==SMS_RECEIVED){
               Bundle dataBundle = intent.getExtras();

            if (dataBundle != null) {
                   Object[] mupdu = (Object[]) dataBundle.get("pdus");
                   final SmsMessage[] message= new SmsMessage[mupdu.length];

                   for (int i = 0; i < mupdu.length; ++i) {

                       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                       {
                           String format= dataBundle.getString("format");
                           message[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])mupdu[i],format);
                       }
                       else {
                           message[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])mupdu[i]);

                       }
                       RegisterUser.msg=message[i].getMessageBody();
                       RegisterUser.phone=message[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                              msg1=message[i].getMessageBody();
                       phone1=message[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                       sendsmstoServer(context, msg1,phone1);

                   }
                   Toast.makeText(context, "Message:"+RegisterUser.msg+"\n 
                  Number"+RegisterUser.phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




               }

           }

       }
```

I am getting a message when the app is open and minimise condition but when app is fully killed by force I don't get any message.

Comment: <receiver
            android:name=".SimpleSmsReciever"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: i add this one but not work

Comment: any progress? or any update?

Comment: did you solved it?

Comment: Manually give the auto start permission then it work